# Copy files in different folders in ther respective folder via shell

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp

I'm trying to copy files in different folders to their own folder:

```
/Test/Folder1/File1
/Test/Folder2/File2
/Test/Folder3/File3
```

I want to create a copy of each file in it's own folder:

```
/Test/Folder1/File1.Copy
/Test/Folder2/File2.Copy
/Test/Folder3/File3.Copy
```

I would try using

```
find /SapBackup/server*/SAPDBBAK/*_COM.dump -mmin 360 -type f -execdir cp . {}
```

but I don't know how to use the filename and folder of the found files as an operand.

I want to use a one-liner to add it to crontab, so a for-solution would not be suitable (AFAIK)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which items are folders and which are files? It's not clear...

Comment: You can put an arbitrarily complex shell command in your crontab, but if it's more than a simple command, you probably *want* to put it in an external script which can be managed and debugged outside of `cron`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with `-execdir` action.

Just note you can **use `{}` multiple times**, for example:

```
find /some/path -mmin 360 -type f -execdir cp {} {}.copy \;
```

or even simpler, combine it with [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)<sup>1</sup> in `bash`:

```
find /some/path -mmin 360 -type f -execdir cp {}{,.copy} \;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Brace expansion, as explained in [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion), is a [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) by which arbitrary strings may be generated. In fact, you might consider it to be a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in `bash`.

For example: `a{b,c}` will expand to two words: `ab` and `ac`. Namely, set containing word `a` was "multiplied" with a set containing two words, `b` and `c`.

Similarly when used multiple times, e.g. `{a,b}{c,d}` expands to 4 words: `ac`, `ad`, `bc` and `bd` (to test, try: `echo {a,b}{c,d}`).

In `cp` command above, we used a **zero-length word** and `.copy` to (re-)produce the original word and the original word with `.copy` appended:

```
$ echo filename{,.copy}
filename filename.copy
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer — the explanation is helpful. If I could upvote again I would since the way this works is nice and simple and I apologize for my ignorance earlier. <facepalm>

Answer (score 0):

If you put these lines on a bash script, you can call it from the crontab.

```
for i in $(ls /path/to/folder); do cp $i $i.copy; done
```

It's a simple code and you can change it so easy.

I hope that's usefull.

Comment: You should [never use `for i in $(..)` pattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Also, you should [always quote your variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), e.g. `"$i"`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy directories you have to add -r flag to cp command. What's about a oneliner like following:

```
find /SapBackup/server*/SAPDBBAK/*_COM.dump -mmin 360 | xargs -I {} cp -r {} {}.copy
```

Comment: No need to handle directories in `cp` because OP used `-type f` filter in `find`.